# Entity framework saving child objects

Tags: frameworks, entity

Im pretty new to entity framework and am having some trouble adjusting. Like all things, in the beginning i saw how much simpler it made my life for CRUD operations and thought it was great. However as my object model grew slightly more complex i began to have more and more issues with it.

Although I have managed to find answers to virtually all my questions by searching on here to date, my current one stumps me.

I have two entities which are linked by a 1 to 1/0 relationship. I cant post images yet so please fogive my dodgy drawing below:

```
Person (id, name, address, dob, etc. etc.)
Spouse (id, name, address, dob, etc. etc.)
```

Whilst the actual is more complex I don't think its part of my problem.

Now, seeing this is a 1 to 0/1 relationship either a person has 1 spouse, or they have 0. If i construct my object by:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Spouse = new Spouse(); 
person.Spouse = spouse;
```

(imagine property setting included)

and then save it. It works a treat. I can then load it again, edit it, etc. etc. Life is grand.

Where I run into problems is where I save a person (no spouse), and then load the person for editing at a later stage and try to attach a spouse. When i get to my container.Attach(person); call, it throws the following exception: "An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context."

Now, I am extremely confident this is due to the way im adding the spouse, ie:

```
Person person = LoadPerson(id);
Spouse spouse = new Spouse();
person.Spouse1 = spouse;
```

The problem im seeing is im trying to now associate a child entity which was not previously associated. I have done a lot of searching on the error message but generally it seems to relate to the object context. Also i have found a work around (from the results i have found). If I use a 1 to many relationship and do Person.Spouses.Add(spouse) it works fine. However im hesitant to do so as the relationship is not logical (in this country anyway...). Im sure its a simple answer which i have obviously overlooked in the results i have seen (i highly doubt im the first to try and do this...) but nothing i have tried seems to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the Spouse to the Context first

```
Context.Spouses.Add(spouse);
```

Before you attach it to the Person.